# How to query all the records with only null or empty fields in solr

Tags: python, solr

I am trying to query only those records which have either null or empty value for an attribute. Suppose my schema have name fields and sirname field now I want to select all the names which have sirname as null or empty in solr. I have tried using:

```
?q=-sirname:["" TO *]
```

But this is giving me all the records.

Comment: try this ?q=-id:["" TO *]...

Comment: This is what I have been, my attribute name is sirname.

Comment: Did you try q=-sirname:[* TO *]